# How to search a word in MySQL table? MATCH AGAINST or LIKE?

Tags: mysql, search, select, sql-like, match-against

I have a table for some companies that may have many branches in different countries. These countries are inserted in `countries` field.
Now, I have to make a searching system that allows users to find companies that have any branch in a specific country.
My question is: Which one do I have to use ? `MATCH AGAINST` or `LIKE` ? The query must search all records to find complete matched items.

- attention: Records may have different country name separated with a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MATCH AGAINST` clause is used in [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

for this you need to create a `full text index` on search column `countries`.

`full text index` search is much faster than `LIKE '%country%'` serach.

Comment: If it matters, be warned that MATCH AGAINST is purely MySQL, so if you ever want to migrate the database you'll have to revisit the search algorithm. It is indeed much, much faster than LIKE, but LIKE is standard and depending on your query optimization could be just fine. You'll have to test to be sure. I'd much rather see you break this into an intermediary company_country table as described by alfasin.

Answer (score 3):

I would change the implementation: having a field that contains multiple values is a *[bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282508/why-is-multi-value-field-a-bad-idea-in-relational-databases)*,  for example, it's difficult to maintain - how will you implement `remove` a country from a company ?.

I believe that a better approach would be to have a separate table **companies_countries** which will have two columns: `company_id` and `country_id`, and could have multiple lines per `company`.

Comment: you are right. The problem I have is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762293/how-to-fetch-ids-while-working-with-jquery-autocomplete-multiple-selection , and it seems that there is no solution for it

Comment: Your other question is a different issue. You can change the implementation and show the chosen countries as a multiple-value field in HTML, but you definitely shouldn't store it as multiple-value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LIKE` . Because as  @Omesh mentioned `MATCH AGAINST` clause is used for **Full Text Search.**. And Full Text Search need entire column for search.